# How to Set the Value of JSpinner from an Integer Variable?

Tags: java

```
int age=12;
spinner.setValue(age);
```

That's my code, I can't set the spinner to 12.

PS. How to set the spinner value from database?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be easily answer by reading [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and the [`JSpinner` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html)

Comment: Autoboxing, introduced in Java 1.5, should allow you to pass an `int` to the `JSpinner`, assuming that the spinner has been configured to accept numerical values. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2):

`setValue` method expects an object as it's arguments. You are trying to set an integer, a primitive type to the method. Use one of the below

```
spinner.setValue(Integer.valueOf(age))
```

or

```
spinner.setValue(Integer.toString(age))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late answer, however: getValue() method expects an Object, so I presume rather not use a primitive data type, therefore in your case, instead of:

> int age = 12

rather this:

> Integer age = 12;
>
> spinner.setValue(age);

Well as for string values this works just fine:

> spinner.setValue("12");

or from a string value, this works just fine too:

> Integer age = Integer.parseInt(yourString);

Open to corrections!

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

> jSpinner1.setValue(Integer.parseInt("3"));